# can i Use a fragment non default constructor with an onSaveInstanceState method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

im creating a fragment that needs to receive an object as part of its initialization
now i read that i need to worry about configuartion changes and therefore use a Bundle.

what i want to know are 2 things:

1)can i set the fragment using a nonDefault constructor (not using a bundle) and handle the bundle part only in the onSaveInstance, or is there a case in which that wont work out?
(i have a default empty constructor for android framework to use if needed)

2)i use an array inside my extention of the Application instance as a pipe to save objects so i wont have to implement the parcelable interface (have lots of objects that are needed to be saved and retained after the changes), is there anything that can go wrong with this approach, if so is there a better way (without implementing serializable or parcelable?)

```
public FragmentAddContactGroups (ContactGroup group)
    {
        if (group!=null)//editin a group
        {
            set_editExisting(true);
            set_groupContactList(group.get_contactsInGroup());
        }
        else //a new group
        {
            set_editExisting(false);
            ContactGroup newGroup=new ContactGroup();
            ArrayList<Contact> array=new ArrayList<>();
            newGroup.set_contactsInGroup(array);
            set_groupContactList(array);
        }
    }
```

the saveinstance method:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
    {
        //save the chosen group
        int id=getApplication().set_pipeItem(get_group());
        outState.putInt(GROUP_KEY,id);//add the pipe id for the item to the bundle
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

the onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        //in case the view is restarted and we edit an existing group get the group from pipe
        if (savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            int itemId=savedInstanceState.getInt(GROUP_KEY);//get the pipe item key
            set_group((ContactGroup)getApplication().get_pipeItem(itemId));
            set_groupContactList(get_group().get_contactsInGroup());
        }

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_add_contact_group, container,
                false);
        setPlaceHolders(rootView);
        assignListeners();
        initView();//create the people list and add it to the view 
        return rootView;
    }
```